# what is the argument "arguments" passed to exec function in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, caching, redis

i've been trying to use cache with redis in my nodejs mongodb application but i didn't find any tutorial on how to do that except few which are using logic that seems to not be explained in mongoose documentation

```
    const exec = mongoose.Query.prototype.exec;
    mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = async 
      function (){
          // our caching logic
          return await exec.apply(this, arguments);
    }
```

where does arguments come from ? because it seems to be undefined yet it is used

```
mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = async function(){
    const collectionName = this.mongooseCollection.name;

    if(this.cacheMe){   
      // You can't insert json straight to redis needs to be a string 

        const key = JSON.stringify({...this.getOptions(),
             collectionName : collectionName, op : this.op});
        const cachedResults = await redis.HGET(collectionName,key);

      // this.op is the method which in our case is "find" 

        if (cachedResults){
          // if you found cached results return it; 
            const result = JSON.parse(cachedResults);
            return result;
        }
     //else 
    // get results from Database then cache it
        const result = await exec.apply(this,arguments); 

        redis.HSET(collectionName, key, JSON.stringify(result) , "EX",this.cacheTime);
       //Blogs - > {op: "find" , ... the original query} -> result we got from database
        return result;
    }

    clearCachedData(collectionName, this.op);
    return exec.apply(this,arguments);
}
```

and what is this.getOptions()?
i would be thankful if any one can explain me this logic, because i did not find any help in the documentations nor internet blogs and articls

Answer (score 1):

The `arguments` object is a local variable that is available inside every function in JavaScript and contains the values of the arguments passed to the function.

`this.getOptions()` is the local method that returns the options to the query.

```json
// A key example for mongoose Redis integration
const key = JSON.stringify({
    collectionName: this.mongooseCollection.name,
    op: this.op,
    options: this.getOptions(),
    filter: this.getFilter(),
    projection: this.projection(),
    populatedPaths: this.getPopulatedPaths(),
  });
```

There are a lot of similar packages on NPM, but I highly recommend standard `mongoose` and `redis` ones to get up and running. I assumed your initialization point was similar to [this](https://dev.to/ahmedmagdy11/building-cache-layer-using-redis-and-mongoose-11kb) post. [This](https://gist.github.com/zisan34/64f502944920550db2347fde9d21ed44) can also be a relevant source.